# AdView missing requied xml attribute adSize in android using google adds

Tags: android

here i need to display adds using google admob.i tried below code but am getting    "AdView missing requied xml attribute adSize" error.

```
  jarfile:GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar

    main.xml:
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample"
              android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a14f1d807e488dd"/>
               </LinearLayout>

     attrs.xml:

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
         <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
  <attr name="adSize">
      <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
      <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
      <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
      <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
  </attr>
  <attr name="adUnitId" format="string"/>
     </declare-styleable>
         </resources>
```

where i did the the wrong plese help me.

Answer (score 0):

4.3.1 no longer uses attrs.xml, I had the same problem.
I suggest re-following the Android AdMob guide here and your problems will be sorted:
http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

Comment: ok using this one i am getting adds.but how to add refresh interval dynamically.

Comment: i am using        adView.loadAd(request);     this code dynamically but adds are not refreshed.                                          in everey 5 secs i need to refresh adds.so what i need to do dynamically.